# Few test cases passed. Why not all?

Tags: java

The code I have written for this question passes only few test cases.I need help with optimising this.

Question:

Marmot , a very weird creature eats balls . At every dinner he eats some red and white balls . Therefore a dinner can be represented as a sequence of several balls , some of them white and some of them red . But for a dinner to be tasty , there is a constraint : Marmot wants to eat white balls only in groups of size K . Now You need to find out “In how many ways can Marmot eat between A and B balls” . As the answer can be very large print it modulo 1000000007 .

Input

First line contains two integers, t and K (1<=t,K<=105 ) where t represents the number of test cases . Next t lines contain two integers A and B (1<=A<=B<=105) describing a test case .

Output

Print t lines , answer for every test case in a single line .

Sample test cases

Input

3 2

1 3

2 3

4 4

Output

6

5

5

Explanation 
R -> Red ball W -> White ball For length 1 and K=2 Marmot can eat ® For length 2 and K=2 Marmot can eat (RR) and (WW) For length 3 and K=2 Marmot can eat (RRR) , (RWW) and (WWR) .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Source {

//Did not use recursive call, as I thought that would increase the running time
public static int factorial(int n) {
    int i,f = 1;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        f *= i;
    }
    return f;
}

public static int arrange(int m, int n, int k){

    // m is total length of balls
    // n is no. of packets of white balls
    // k is size of each packet

    int r,p,arrange;
    r = m-(n*k); // r - no. of red balls
    p = n+r; // p - no. of items to be shuffled
    arrange = factorial(p)/factorial(r)/factorial(n);
    return arrange;
}

public static void main(String args[]){

    int i,j,l,t=0,k=0,A=-1,B=-1,q,ansforj,answer,arrans;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (sc.hasNextInt())
        t = sc.nextInt();
    if (sc.hasNextInt())
        k = sc.nextInt();

    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        answer=0;
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
            A = sc.nextInt();
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
            B = sc.nextInt();
        for(j=A;j<=B;j++){
            q = j/k;
            ansforj=0;
            for(l=0;l<=q;l++){
                arrans = arrange(j,l,k);
                ansforj = ansforj + arrans;
            }
            answer = answer + ansforj;
            answer = answer % 1000000007;
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
        }
    sc.close();
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Also, when you have comments like `m is total length of balls`, you're naming your variables wrong.  You should name it something useful, for example, `totalLengthOfBalls`.

Comment: How come the answer for 4 4 (exactly 4 balls) is 5? Is (WWWW) (two groups @ 2 white balls in a row) a valid answer?

Comment: Are you sure you can handle inputs up to 105 correctly? I believe the factorial of 105 has some 166 digits in it, where a Java `int` can store up to 9 or 10 digits.

Comment: @OleV.V., for 4 4, we have RRRR, WWRR, RWWR, RRWW, WWWW

Comment: Then I have understood correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few test examples to get you started thinking about why your program doesn’t work as it should. I use K = 1. If I understand correctly this should be the same as no restriction on the meal. So for a meal of b balls there are 2 ^ b possibilities since each ball can be eihter red or white.

Input:

```
3 1
12 12
13 13
34 34
```

Expected output

```
4096
8192
179869065
```

Actual output

```
4096
2538
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Source.arrange(Source.java:26)
    at Source.main(Source.java:51)
```

Comment: @Ole.V.V., I have tried using long. It still isn't working.Can you please help me with this?Thank you.

Comment: I have been thinking about it, but I have not reached a final opinion on the best way to proceed. A `long` holds like 19 digits (decimal digits), it’s still pretty far from 166 digits. I am thinking of two options: (1) Doing the calculations of the division of factorials in a smarter way where you exploit the fact that you only need a result modulo 1000000007. (2) Using `BigInteger`. There are probably more options I haven’t thought about.

Comment: I believe the greatest number `arrange()` needs to return is 105! / 53! / 52! It won’t fit in a `long`. Not until you do the modulo 1000000007 operation.

Comment: The only way I could think of doing the smarter division was if you represent each number as a list of coefficients of prime factors. For example, 12 is 2 ^ 2 * 3 ^ 1, so represent as [2, 1] or [2, 1, 0, 0, …]. Multiplication is done by adding coefficients and division by subtracting them. You need to find the prime factorization of all numbers from 1 through 105, that’s manageable. It will require some amount of coding, though.

Comment: `BigInteger` is certainly easier if its performance is good enough. I should say it’s worth trying.

Comment: @Ole.V.V., Thanks a lot! It works with `BigInteger` :)

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. May I add? There are some good practices in program testing. The one I use most actively is testing the limit. For instance, when 1 <= t <= 105, test with t = 1 and with t = 105 (in real world, also test that t = 0 and t = 106 give proper error messages). Same for other inputs. For instance, test with A = B = 1, with A = B = 105 and with A = 1 and B = 105.